# How to rewrite an expression containing a symmetric operator

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

I am dealing with the Schrodinger operator, $$S = -\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+p(x).$$

Let $f$ be a function satisfying $$Sf = k^2 f, \ \ \ k^2\in\mathbb{R} \ \ \ \  (1)$$ also let $g$ satisfy this same equation.

I have the expression $\int(fSg)dx$ but I would like to 'swap' $f$ and $g$ in the integral. That is I want to express it as $S$ acting on something to do with $f$ rather than $g$. Here is my attempt:

Let $(f,g) = \int{\bar{f} g}dx$ be the inner product.

Then $\int(fSg)dx = (\bar{f},Sg)$ but now using that $S$ is symmetric, $$(\bar{f}, Sg) = \overline{(g, S\bar{f})} = \overline{\int \bar{g} S\bar{f}dx}  $$

Note that $S\bar{f} = k^2 \bar{f}$ since $f$ satisfies $(1)$ above.
Putting it all together then we get 
$$(\bar{f}, Sg) =  k^2\int gf dx$$

Are these manipulations correct?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int (fSg) dx= \int (f(x) k^2 g(x)) dx= \int (g(x) k^2 f(x)) dx = \int (gSf) dx
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Which gives the same answer! :)